# What word describes this form of unreadability best?

Tags: word-choice

If a headline is difficult to read because it is written in all-caps and the words lack form but each individual letter is clear, is it illegible, unreadable, or something else?

Comment: To me, illegible gives a connotation of unclear lettering, but when I read the definition, it looks like it would be a valid word here.   Personally, though, I would go with simply calling it unreadable or indecipherable, if I'm reading you right, and the writing is SOMETHINGLIKETHIS.

Comment: I would suggest *unintelligible* or *incomprehensible* both meaning difficult to understand. People read by word wholes, and are far more used to the shape of lower case letters to read the word wholes. All capitals makes it much harder to read the individual words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wikipedia's article on [ALL CAPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) indicates, it is *legibility* which is affected. While it doesn't state that the text becomes *completely illegible*, it notes that the practice leads to *low legibility*.

Bad handwriting is considered to be [cacographic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cacography).

While I don't think that they really address the fact that the individual letters are clear, you can also consider [incoherent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incoherent) and [indistinct](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indistinct).

Answer (score 2):

Its both "less legible and less readable". The words illegible and unreadable are too strong.  Besides the legibility of the headline depends on the context, like a newspaper daily having its name on the top most headline of the newspaper, a form of art(calligraphy), etc. They can also mean shouting, if used in emails and such media.

Comment: I agree, and I might even be inclined to call it _less pleasing_, if I could still read the words just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of the headline, you might call it [ambiguous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambiguous?q=ambiguous), [incomprehensible](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incomprehensible?q=incomprehensible), or [incoherent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incoherent).

Ambiguous (open to more than one interpretation--*now here* vs. *nowhere*):

> JOHNISNOWHERE

Incomprehensible (no meaning at all can be extracted):

> BLAHEDFRGOWHECHLEMINGFRUD

Incoherent (words with apparent meaning, but used illogically or inconsistently):

> FREDTHEBOBBININTOGREENANDSPACKLEBLUNT

Comment: But wouldn't these all hold true, even if the letters were all in lower case? In other words, for your first example, you've answered a kerning/spacing question, not a capitalization question.

Comment: True, I haven't really addressed the capitalization specifically.